# CubeMap direction issue in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to use Vulkan to make a cubemap. I follow the key points in "https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/texturecubemap/texturecubemap.cpp." And use the skybox pictures as attachment. [image]

The issue is shown in the attachment as well. The directions of the top and bottom pictures aren't correct.
[image]

I am trying to rotate the points for the top and bottom squares as below.

```
            {{-1, 1, -1}},
            {{1, 1, -1}},
            {{1, 1, 1}},
            {{1, 1, 1}},
            {{-1, 1, 1}},
            {{-1, 1, -1}},
```

to

```
            {{1, 1, -1}},
            {{1, 1, 1}},
            {{-1, 1, 1}},
            {{-1, 1, 1}},
            {{-1, 1, -1}},
            {{1, 1, -1}},
```

but has no effect at all. Has someone met situation like this? Thanks! (I haven't met situation like this in OpenGL)

Comment: The order of the triangles doesn't matter, it just needs to be a mesh that fully surrounds the scene so that you can cast a ray through the cubemap. The problem is the order of the faces. If the top and bottom face doesn't line up shift the order of the side faces until everything lines up.

Comment: @vandench, thanks for replying, may you shed any light on how to shift the order of the side faces? Many thanks.

Comment: @vandench, I understand what you mean and fix the issue, thank so much!